# Items in ListView not retaining their values

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView with a custom adapter and each item has a title and a description Button that makes a Dialog pop up, each item having a unique description. Everything seems to be working except after scrolling around a little bit, the description button pulls up the wrong description. From what I understand, something must be happening behind the scenes in ListView that's causing it to not bind the right values to the items after scrolling. I'm suspicious that the problem might be that I'm setting the OnItemClickListener on the ListView in the Activity class, as well as the behavior for each Button. The following code is from the Activity that contains the ListView.

```
lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            //CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            //checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());
            final View tempView = view;
            LinearLayout countLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.counter_layout);
            TextView count = (TextView) countLayout.findViewById(R.id.counter);
            ImageView add = (ImageView) countLayout.findViewById(R.id.add_sign);
            ImageView minus = (ImageView) countLayout.findViewById(R.id.minus_sign);
            ImageView description = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.info_button);
            minus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    list.get(position).setCount(list.get(position).getCount() - 1);
                    LinearLayout countLayout = (LinearLayout) tempView.findViewById(R.id.counter_layout);
                    TextView count = (TextView) countLayout.findViewById(R.id.counter);
                    count.setText("" + list.get(position).getCount());
                    try {

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        writeObject(getApplicationContext(), "checklist", new Lists(list, customList));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Change not saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                }
            });
            add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    list.get(position).setCount(list.get(position).getCount() + 1);
                    LinearLayout countLayout = (LinearLayout) tempView.findViewById(R.id.counter_layout);
                    TextView count = (TextView) countLayout.findViewById(R.id.counter);
                    count.setText("" + list.get(position).getCount());
                    try {
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        writeObject(getApplicationContext(), "checklist", new Lists(list, customList));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Change not saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                }
            });
            description.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ChecklistActivity.this)
                            .setTitle("Description")
                            .setMessage(list.get(position).getDescription())
                            .setPositiveButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    //Do Nothing
                                }
                            })
                            .create();
                    alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                    alert.show();
                }
            });


        }

    });
```

Comment: Have you tried using a RecyclerView or using the ViewHolder pattern? When you scroll, views are recycled

Comment: Wrong place to initialise a button that is a part of a listview item. Your on click listener also has no position information. It uses a random position value. So this can never go ok.  Even before scrolling this will not work.  You should put listeners in getView() on every button separately. Dont need a recycler view for that.

Comment: Thank you, the counter on each item appears to be working correctly now. The problem i am having now though is with the description button since it creates an AlertDialog. Can I show an AlertDialog from the Adapter or how can I send the correct position int to the Activity so that I can display the correct description for each item?